# Swift SpriteKit .atlas folder naming (@2x)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sprite, atlas

I'm playing around with SpriteKit and I just made my first simple sprite animation. I have a folder example.atlas with 2 pictures in it:
image_1.png
image_2.png
and it works perfectly. But when I throw in 2 more pictures:
image_1@2x.png
image_2@2x.png
with a higher resolution I get red X's in my animation. Do I have to create a second .atlas folder with example@2x.atlas or how can I include my high resolution pictures in my project?

Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hardware specific atlas with Sprite Kit is blown up on iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21389481/hardware-specific-atlas-with-sprite-kit-is-blown-up-on-ipad)

Comment: @TheCodingArt not a duplicate of that question... I already tried to put all of my images in the same atlas folder but the animation displays red X's when I do ...

Comment: it's the same exact thing. The red Xs mean the images do not exist or are not being registered correctly. If you add both your retina and non retina images correctly to the atlas and are running on a respective device (retina or non retina), the images should appear correctly. Also note the bug reports in the previous post. Your question may not be _exactly_ the same, but it definitely is the same concept and resolution. You should definitely google this stuff first.

Comment: The images exist 100% I tripple checked and the problem only occurs when I put the @2x pictures in the same atlas folder. And I googled but I cant find anyone with the same problem as me...

Comment: @user2403221 What device / sim you are testing on? What Xcode do you use?.Have you tried cleaning your project : Product -> Clean... As well as reseting Simulator's content and settings . Stuff like that?